# How to remove package libboost-system1.58.0? currently have unmet dependencies

Tags: package-management, dependencies, boost

I have boost library 1.58 installed from default repository and an older version installed from source. Now I wanna remove the boost 1.58.

First I did was to remove the `libboost-all-dev` package, but there are still four packages left installed, two of which I remove separately, and two I just cannot remove. These two packages are: `libboost-system1.58.0` and `libboost-filesystem1.58.0`. Whenever I do `sudo apt-get --purge remove libboost-system1.58.0` there are unmet dependencies errors, which relates to `qt`, which I have no idea why it has anything to do with.

The error output looks like this:

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 liboxideqt-qmlplugin : Depends: libqt5quick5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                                 libqt5quick5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 liboxideqtcore0 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.4.0) but it is not going to be installed or
                            libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
 liboxideqtquick0 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                             libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                    Depends: libqt5quick5 (>= 5.2.0) but it is not going to be installed or
                             libqt5quick5-gles (>= 5.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
 libqmenumodel0 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                           libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt5multimedia5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.2.0) but it is not going to be installed or
                              libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt5multimediaquick-p5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                                     libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                            Depends: libqt5quick5 (>= 5.4.0) but it is not going to be installed or
                                     libqt5quick5-gles (>= 5.4.0) but it is not going to be installed
 libqt5x11extras5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                             libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libubuntugestures5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                               libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                      Depends: libqt5quick5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                               libqt5quick5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 libubuntutoolkit5 : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                              libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 qml-module-io-thp-pyotherside : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                                          libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                                 Depends: libqt5quick5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                                          libqt5quick5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 qml-module-qtquick-layouts : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.5.0) but it is not going to be installed or
                                       libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.5.0) but it is not going to be installed
                              Depends: libqt5quick5 (>= 5.2.0) but it is not going to be installed or
                                       libqt5quick5-gles (>= 5.2.0) but it is not going to be installed
 qml-module-ubuntu-layouts : Depends: libqt5quick5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                                      libqt5quick5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
 qml-module-ubuntu-performancemetrics : Depends: libqt5gui5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                                                 libqt5gui5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
                                        Depends: libqt5quick5 (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed or
                                                 libqt5quick5-gles (>= 5.0.2) but it is not going to be installed
```

My first question is, why is this package `libboost-system1.58.0` has anything to do with `qt`? I looked up in the ubuntu package page, neither these qt packages depend on `libboost-system1.58.0` nor does `libboost-system1.58.0` depends on these qt packages.

My second question is, is this package `libboost-system1.58.0` really relevant? I remember I installed boost with `apt-get install libboost-all-dev`, but apparently `libboost-system1.58.0` is not in the dependecy list to `libboost-all-dev`. So where does this package come from?

The third question might not be related to this problem, but I looked through these `qt packages` when I check them, I saw they all have duplicate packages with different versions, for example:

```
liboxideqtcore0/xenial-updates,xenial-security,now 1.21.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 amd64 [installed,automatic]
liboxideqtcore0/xenial 1.13.6-0ubuntu1 amd64
```

So does this relate to my problem here?

---

I have added the output for `apt-cache policy libboost-filesystem1.58.0 liboxideqt-qmlplugin`:

```
libboost-filesystem1.58.0:
  Installed: 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1
  Candidate: 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1
  Version table:
 *** 1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3.1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.58.0+dfsg-5ubuntu3 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
liboxideqt-qmlplugin:
  Installed: 1.21.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  Candidate: 1.21.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
  Version table:
 *** 1.21.5-0ubuntu0.16.04.1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.13.6-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Please add output of `apt-cache policy libboost-filesystem1.58.0 liboxideqt-qmlplugin` to the question. Do you have any boost- and qt-related PPAs added to the system?

Comment: @N0rbert Thanks for your reply, I attached the output in the end of my question. And, no I do not have boost- and qt-related PPAs. But I do notice I have packages from qt4 and qt5 coexisting.

Comment: What is interesting I got the same result on my every-day real system. Seems to be packaging bug. You can simply ignore it.

Comment: @N0rbert I am trying to remove these qt packages..I just don't know where they come from. They have both qt4 and 5, which is really strange.

Comment: @N0rbert Hi. I just found out that the libboost-filesystem1.58.0 and the other libboost package are pre-installed by ubuntu 16.04. So I think I will just leave it there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR.** The short answer to the question - it is dependencies issue. So you can not remove this package.

## Analysis

The longer variant is to evaluate an analysis to determine the reason why `libboost-filesystem1.58.0` was installed, which packages depend on it and can we safely remove it.

### Why `libboost-filesystem1.58.0` and `libboost-system1.58.0` were installed

To answer the first (*why*) question we can use Aptitude with its `why` command.

On my clean fully updated Ubuntu MATE 16.04 LTS I get the following output

> ```
> $ aptitude why libboost-filesystem1.58.0
> i   libmircommon5 Depends libboost-filesystem1.58.0
> ```

the latter `libmircommon5` was installed because of LightDM:

> ```
> $ aptitude why libmircommon5
> i   lightdm Recommends unity-greeter | lightdm-greeter | lightdm-kde-greeter
> ```

The system library -

> ```
> $ aptitude why libboost-system1.58.0
> i   libmirclient9 Depends libboost-system1.58.0
> ```

On Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with default Unity the situation is even worse:

> ```
> $ aptitude why libboost-filesystem1.58.0
> i   ubuntu-desktop  Depends update-notifier                         
> i A update-notifier Depends libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.0.0)                   
> i A libgtk-3-0      Depends libmirclient9 (>= 0.21.0+16.04.20160330)
> i A libmirclient9   Depends libmircommon7 (>= 0.26.3+16.04.20170605)
> i A libmircommon7   Depends libboost-filesystem1.58.0
> ```

### Which packages depend on `libboost-filesystem1.58.0`

To answer the second (*which dependencies*) we can use `rdepend` of `apt-cache` to get the list of reverse dependencies (this means why the `libboost-filesystem1.58.0` was installed)

> ```
> $ apt-cache rdepends libboost-filesystem1.58.0
> libboost-filesystem1.58.0
> Reverse Depends:
>   mir-utils
>   mir-test-tools
>   libboost-log1.58.0
>   libboost-filesystem1.58-dev
>   juju-mongodb3.2
>   libmircommon7
>   vcmi
>   openmw-launcher
>   openmw-cs
>   openmw
>   ycmd
>   witty-examples
>   wesnoth-1.12-server
>   wesnoth-1.12-core
>   undertaker
>   uhd-host
>   ubuntu-location-service-tests
>   ubuntu-location-service-bin
>   tomahawk
>   tmfs
>   thumbnailer-service
>   synfig
>   supercollider-supernova
>   supercollider-language
>   sslsniff
>   ssh-agent-filter
>   springlobby
>   spring
>   sitplus
>   sfftobmp
>   rviz
>   rsbackup
>   rlvm
>   python3-woo
>   python-yade
>   python-woo
>   python-ledger
>   python-fife
>   pulseview
>   progressivemauve
>   pokerth-server
>   pokerth
>   plee-the-bear
>   performous-tools
>   performous
>   pcl-tools
>   orthanc
>   openscad-testing
>   openscad
>   ncmpcpp
>   murasaki-mpi
>   murasaki
>   mupen64plus-video-glide64mk2
>   mtp-server
>   mrs
>   mongodb-server
>   mongodb-clients
>   mkvtoolnix-gui
>   mkvtoolnix
>   mira-assembler
>   mir-test-tools
>   mia-tools
>   lightspark-common
>   libzeep3.0v5
>   libyade
>   libwt38
>   libvolk1-bin
>   liburdf0d
>   libunity-scopes1.0
>   libunity-scopes-cli
>   libuhd003
>   libtrust-store2
>   libthumbnailer-qt1.0
>   libsdformat4
>   librviz0d
>   librospack0d
>   libroscpp0d
>   librosbag0d
>   librime1
>   libqpidcommon2
>   libpwiz3
>   libpwiz-tools
>   libpion-plugins
>   libpion-net-plugins
>   libpion-net-dev
>   libpion-dev
>   libpion-common-4.0
>   libpion-5.0
>   libpcl-visualization1.7
>   libpcl-outofcore1.7
>   libpcl-io1.7
>   libpam-barada
>   libosl1v5
>   libopenimageio1.6
>   libodil0
>   libnodeletlib0d
>   libmia-2.2-4
>   libmems-1.6-1v5
>   libmapnik3.0
>   liblucene++0v5
>   libimage-transport0d
>   libgnuradio-wavelet3.7.9
>   libgnuradio-runtime3.7.9
>   libgnuradio-fft3.7.9
>   libgnuradio-fec3.7.9
>   libgazebo7
>   libflightcrew0v5
>   libcollada-urdf0d
>   libcollada-dom2.4-dp0
>   libcnoid1
>   libcamera-calibration-parsers0d
>   libboost-log1.58.0
>   libboost-filesystem1.58-dev
>   libasl0
>   libaqsis1
>   lgogdownloader
>   ledger
>   laserboy
>   kcollectd
>   juju-mongodb3.2
>   juju-mongodb2.6
>   juju-mongodb
>   innoextract
>   image-transport-tools
>   hugin-tools
>   hhvm
>   gpsshogi
>   gource
>   gnss-sdr
>   gdf-tools
>   gazebo7-plugin-base
>   gazebo7
>   freeorion
>   freelan
>   esys-particle
>   enfuse
>   enblend
>   dchroot-dsa
>   dchroot
>   dbus-cpp-bin
>   darkradiant-plugins-darkmod
>   darkradiant
>   colobot
>   ckon
>   choreonoid-plugins-base
>   cclive
>   btag
>   bombono-dvd
>   blender
>   bear-factory
>   aqsis
>   aegisub
>   0ad
>   libdbus-cpp5
>   schroot
>   libmircommon5
>
> $ apt-cache rdepends libboost-system1.58.0
> libboost-system1.58.0
> Reverse Depends:
>   mir-utils
>   mir-test-tools
>   mir-demos
>   libboost-wave1.58.0
>   libboost-system1.58-dev
>   libboost-log1.58.0
>   libboost-locale1.58.0
>   libboost-chrono1.58.0
>   juju-mongodb3.2
>   ceph-test
>   ceph-mds
>   rbd-nbd
>   rbd-mirror
>   rbd-fuse
>   radosgw
>   mir-platform-graphics-mesa-x12
>   mir-platform-graphics-mesa-kms12
>   librgw2
>   librbd1
>   libradosstriper1
>   librados2
>   librados-dev
>   libmirserver43
>   libmirplatform15
>   libmircommon7
>   libmirclient9
>   libcephfs1
>   libcephfs-jni
>   libboost-thread1.58.0
>   libboost-random1.58.0
>   libboost-filesystem1.58.0
>   ceph-fuse
>   ceph-common
>   ceph
>   vcmi
>   openmw-launcher
>   openmw-cs
>   openmw
>   frogatto
>   ycmd
>   witty-examples
>   wesnoth-1.12-server
>   wesnoth-1.12-core
>   voxbo
>   vera++
>   vdr-plugin-fritzbox
>   unity-system-compositor
>   undertaker
>   uhd-host
>   ubuntu-location-service-tests
>   ubuntu-location-service-bin
>   tophat
>   tomahawk
>   tmfs
>   thumbnailer-service
>   tf2-tools
>   tf-tools
>   synfig
>   supercollider-supernova
>   supercollider-language
>   sslsniff
>   ssh-agent-filter
>   springlobby
>   spring
>   soundscaperenderer-nox
>   soundscaperenderer
>   solarpowerlog
>   snapper
>   sitplus
>   sinfo
>   sfftobmp
>   sdrangelove
>   rviz
>   rsbackup
>   rlvm
>   qutecom
>   qbittorrent-nox
>   qbittorrent
>   python3-woo
>   python3-libtorrent-dbg
>   python3-libtorrent
>   python-yade
>   python-woo
>   python-tf2
>   python-tf
>   python-rosbag
>   python-rdkit
>   python-libtorrent-dbg
>   python-libtorrent
>   python-libavg
>   python-ledger
>   python-fife
>   pulseview
>   progressivemauve
>   prepair
>   povray
>   pokerth-server
>   pokerth
>   poedit
>   pluginlib-dev
>   plee-the-bear
>   performous-tools
>   performous
>   pcl-tools
>   osm2pgsql
>   orthanc
>   openscad-testing
>   openscad
>   openimageio-tools
>   ogre-1.9-tools
>   ncmpcpp
>   murasaki-mpi
>   murasaki
>   mupen64plus-video-glide64mk2
>   mtp-server
>   mrs
>   mpikmeans-tools
>   mongodb-server
>   mongodb-clients
>   molds
>   mkvtoolnix-gui
>   mkvtoolnix
>   mira-assembler
>   mir-test-tools
>   mir-platform-graphics-mesa-x8
>   mir-platform-graphics-mesa-kms8
>   mia-viewit
>   mia-tools
>   media-hub
>   lightspark-common
>   libzeep3.0v5
>   libyade
>   libwttest8
>   libwthttp38
>   libwtfcgi38
>   libwtext38
>   libwtdbo38
>   libwt38
>   libvolk1-bin
>   liburdf0d
>   libunity-scopes1.0
>   libunity-scopes-cli
>   libuhd003
>   libubuntu-location-service3
>   libubuntu-download-manager-client1
>   libtrust-store2
>   libtorrent-rasterbar8
>   libtomahawk
>   libthumbnailer-qt1.0
>   libtf2-ros0d
>   libtf2-0d
>   libtf0d
>   libsnapper2v5
>   libsfcgal1
>   libsdformat4
>   librviz0d
>   librostime0d
>   librospack0d
>   libroslib0d
>   libroscpp0d
>   librosconsole0d
>   librosbag0d
>   librime1
>   librime-bin
>   librdkit1
>   librandom-numbers0d
>   libpwiz3
>   libpwiz-tools
>   libpion-plugins
>   libpion-net-plugins
>   libpion-net-dev
>   libpion-net-4.0
>   libpion-dev
>   libpion-common-4.0
>   libpion-5.0
>   libphonenumber7
>   libpcl-visualization1.7
>   libpcl-outofcore1.7
>   libpcl-io1.7
>   libpcl-common1.7
>   libpcl-apps1.7
>   libpam-barada
>   libosl1v5
>   liborigin2-1v5
>   libopenvdb3.1
>   libopenvdb-tools
>   libopenimageio1.6
>   libopencv-apps0d
>   libompl10
>   libogre-1.9.0v5
>   libodil0
>   libnodeletlib0d
>   libnodeletlib-tools
>   libnet-cpp2
>   libmygui.ogreplatform0debian1v5
>   libmia-2.2-4
>   libmems-1.6-1v5
>   libmapnik3.0
>   liblucene++0v5
>   liblucene++-contrib0v5
>   liblaser-geometry0d
>   libkolabxml1v5
>   libinteractive-markers0d
>   libimage-transport0d
>   libicinga2
>   libgnuradio-zeromq3.7.9
>   libgnuradio-wxgui3.7.9
>   libgnuradio-wavelet3.7.9
>   libgnuradio-vocoder3.7.9
>   libgnuradio-video-sdl3.7.9
>   libgnuradio-uhd3.7.9
>   libgnuradio-trellis3.7.9
>   libgnuradio-runtime3.7.9
>   libgnuradio-rds3.7.0
>   libgnuradio-qtgui3.7.9
>   libgnuradio-pmt3.7.9
>   libgnuradio-pager3.7.9
>   libgnuradio-osmosdr0.1.4
>   libgnuradio-noaa3.7.9
>   libgnuradio-iqbalance0
>   libgnuradio-hpsdr0
>   libgnuradio-fosphor3.7.0
>   libgnuradio-filter3.7.9
>   libgnuradio-fft3.7.9
>   libgnuradio-fec3.7.9
>   libgnuradio-fcdproplus0
>   libgnuradio-fcd3.7.9
>   libgnuradio-dtv3.7.9
>   libgnuradio-digital3.7.9
>   libgnuradio-comedi3.7.9
>   libgnuradio-channels3.7.9
>   libgnuradio-blocks3.7.9
>   libgnuradio-audio3.7.9
>   libgnuradio-atsc3.7.9
>   libgnuradio-analog3.7.9
>   libgazebo7
>   libflightcrew0v5
>   libfield3d1.6
>   libfcl0
>   libeiskaltdcpp2.2
>   libdynamic-reconfigure-config-init-mutex0d
>   libdavix0v5
>   libcpprest2.8
>   libcppnetlib0
>   libcollada-urdf0d
>   libcollada-parser0d
>   libcollada-dom2.4-dp0
>   libcnoid1
>   libclass-loader0d
>   libcgal-ipelets
>   libcegui-mk2-0.8.4
>   libcamera-info-manager0d
>   libcamera-calibration-parsers0d
>   libboost-wave1.58.0
>   libboost-system1.58-dev
>   libboost-log1.58.0
>   libboost-locale1.58.0
>   libboost-chrono1.58.0
>   libbondcpp0d
>   libasl0
>   libaqsis1
>   libair-modes0v5
>   libadolc2
>   libactionlib0d
>   lgogdownloader
>   ledger
>   laserboy
>   krita
>   kicad
>   kcollectd
>   juju-mongodb3.2
>   juju-mongodb2.6
>   juju-mongodb
>   innoextract
>   image-transport-tools
>   icinga2-studio
>   icinga2-ido-pgsql
>   icinga2-ido-mysql
>   icinga2-bin
>   hugin-tools
>   hhvm
>   guitarix
>   gr-rds
>   gr-osmosdr
>   gr-iqbal
>   gr-hpsdr
>   gr-fosphor
>   gr-fcdproplus
>   gr-air-modes
>   gqrx-sdr
>   gpsshogi
>   gource
>   gnuradio
>   gnss-sdr
>   glob2
>   gdf-tools
>   gazebo7-plugin-base
>   gazebo7
>   funguloids
>   freeorion
>   freelan
>   freecad
>   flamerobin
>   field3d-bin
>   esys-particle
>   enfuse
>   enblend
>   eiskaltdcpp-qt-mini
>   eiskaltdcpp-qt
>   eiskaltdcpp-gtk3
>   eiskaltdcpp-gtk
>   eiskaltdcpp-daemon
>   dssp
>   dchroot-dsa
>   dchroot
>   dbus-cpp-bin
>   darkradiant-plugins-darkmod
>   darkradiant
>   colobot
>   ckon
>   choreonoid-plugins-base
>   ceph-test
>   ceph-mds
>   cclive
>   btfs
>   btag
>   bombono-dvd
>   blender
>   bear-factory
>   autodock-vina
>   aqsis
>   anytun
>   amule-utils-gui
>   amule-utils
>   amule-daemon
>   amule
>   aegisub
>   ceph
>   schroot
>   rbd-nbd
>   rbd-mirror
>   rbd-fuse
>   radosgw
>   librgw2
>   librbd1
>   libradosstriper1
>   librados2
>   librados-dev
>   liborcus-0.10-0v5
>   libmirserver38
>   libmirplatform11
>   libmircommon5
>   libmirclient9
>   libixion-0.10-0v5
>   libdbus-cpp5
>   libcephfs1
>   libcephfs-jni
>   libboost-thread1.58.0
>   libboost-random1.58.0
>   libboost-filesystem1.58.0
>   ceph-fuse
>   ceph-common
> ```

### Can I remove the `libboost-filesystem1.58.0` and use the system as before?

So can it be removed? Let's run the simulation of its removal on system with MATE:

> ```
> $ apt-get remove --simulate libboost-filesystem1.58.0
> NOTE: This is only a simulation!
>       apt-get needs root privileges for real execution.
>       Keep also in mind that locking is deactivated,
>       so don't depend on the relevance to the real current situation!
> Reading package lists... Done
> Building dependency tree       
> Reading state information... Done
> The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
>   freepats libcapnp-0.5.3 libde265-0 libfluidsynth1 libgtkglext1 libmimic0 libmircore1 libmjpegutils-2.1-0 libmms0 libmpeg2encpp-2.1-0
>   libmplex2-2.1-0 libofa0 libopenal-data libopenal1 libopencv-calib3d2.4v5 libopencv-contrib2.4v5 libopencv-features2d2.4v5 libopencv-flann2.4v5
>   libopencv-highgui2.4v5 libopencv-legacy2.4v5 libopencv-ml2.4v5 libopencv-objdetect2.4v5 libopencv-video2.4v5 libsoundtouch1 libspandsp2 libsrtp0
>   libvo-aacenc0 libvo-amrwbenc0 libwebpdemux1 libwildmidi-config libwildmidi1 libxfont2 libzbar0
> Use 'apt autoremove' to remove them.
> The following packages will be REMOVED:
>   a11y-profile-manager-indicator account-plugin-facebook account-plugin-flickr account-plugin-google adwaita-icon-theme apport-gtk apturl atril
>   bamfdaemon blueman brasero brasero-cdrkit caja cheese compiz compiz-gnome compiz-mate dconf-editor deja-dup deja-dup-backend-cloudfiles
>   deja-dup-backend-gvfs deja-dup-backend-s3 deja-dup-caja firefox folder-color-caja galculator gcr gdebi gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 gir1.2-gtk-3.0
>   gir1.2-peas-1.0 gir1.2-rb-3.0 gir1.2-vte-2.91 gir1.2-webkit-3.0 gir1.2-webkit2-4.0 gir1.2-wnck-3.0 gnome-disk-utility gnome-icon-theme
>   gnome-icon-theme-symbolic gnome-keyring gnome-orca gnome-session-canberra gnome-system-tools gstreamer1.0-clutter-3.0 gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad
>   gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-faad gstreamer1.0-plugins-bad-videoparsers gucharmap gufw gvfs-backends humanity-icon-theme indicator-application
>   indicator-application-gtk2 language-selector-gnome libaccount-plugin-1.0-0 libaccount-plugin-generic-oauth libaccount-plugin-google
>   libappindicator3-1 libatrilview3 libboost-filesystem1.58.0 libbrasero-media3-1 libcanberra-gtk3-0 libcanberra-gtk3-module libcheese-gtk25
>   libcheese8 libclutter-1.0-0 libclutter-gst-3.0-0 libclutter-gtk-1.0-0 libcogl-pango20 libcogl-path20 libcogl20 libegl1-mesa libgcr-ui-3-1
>   libgnome-desktop-3-12 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0 libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgucharmap-2-90-7 libido3-0.1-0 libindicator3-7
>   libkeybinder-3.0-0 libmetacity-private3a libmirclient9 libmircommon5 libmircommon7 libnautilus-extension1a libnm-gtk0 libnma0 libpeas-1.0-0
>   libpeas-1.0-0-python3loader libplank1 libqt5gui5 libqt5libqgtk2 libqt5widgets5 libqt5x11extras5 libreoffice-avmedia-backend-gstreamer
>   librhythmbox-core9 libtopmenu-client-gtk3-0 libtopmenu-server-gtk3-0 libunity-control-center1 libvte-2.91-0 libwayland-egl1-mesa
>   libwebkit2gtk-4.0-37 libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 libwnck-3-0 libyelp0 lightdm-gtk-greeter lightdm-gtk-greeter-settings marco
>   mate-applet-topmenu mate-applets mate-control-center mate-desktop mate-desktop-environment-core mate-dock-applet mate-gnome-main-menu-applet
>   mate-indicator-applet mate-panel mate-screensaver mate-session-manager mate-tweak mate-user-guide network-manager-gnome
>   network-manager-pptp-gnome onboard onboard-data pinentry-gnome3 plank python3-aptdaemon.gtk3widgets rhythmbox rhythmbox-plugin-cdrecorder
>   rhythmbox-plugins seahorse sessioninstaller shotwell simple-scan software-properties-gtk synapse system-config-printer-gnome thunderbird
>   thunderbird-locale-en thunderbird-locale-en-us tilda topmenu-gtk3 transmission-gtk ubuntu-mate-artwork ubuntu-mate-default-settings
>   ubuntu-mate-icon-themes ubuntu-mate-lightdm-theme ubuntu-mate-themes ubuntu-mate-welcome ubuntu-mono ubuntu-release-upgrader-gtk unity-asset-pool
>   update-manager update-notifier usb-creator-gtk vlc xdg-user-dirs-gtk xorg xserver-xorg-core-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04
>   xserver-xorg-input-all-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-input-evdev-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-input-synaptics-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-input-wacom-hwe-16.04
>   xserver-xorg-video-all-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-amdgpu-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-ati-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-fbdev-hwe-16.04
>   xserver-xorg-video-intel-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-nouveau-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-qxl-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-radeon-hwe-16.04
>   xserver-xorg-video-vesa-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-video-vmware-hwe-16.04 xul-ext-lightning yelp zenity
> 0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 181 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
> ```

The above means that we will lose desktop environment and whole X11 system if we remove the `libboost-filesystem1.58.0` package.

The simulation for the Unity-based system ends with the errors from your question.

Answer (score 0):

May be the problem be in the apt source list, see bellow steps on: https://icinga.com/docs/icinga-2/latest/doc/02-installation/02-Ubuntu/

```
apt-get update
apt-get -y install apt-transport-https wget gnupg

wget -O - https://packages.icinga.com/icinga.key | apt-key add -

. /etc/os-release; if [ ! -z ${UBUNTU_CODENAME+x} ]; then DIST="${UBUNTU_CODENAME}"; else DIST="$(lsb_release -c| awk '{print $2}')"; fi; \
 echo "deb https://packages.icinga.com/ubuntu icinga-${DIST} main" > \
 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/${DIST}-icinga.list
 echo "deb-src https://packages.icinga.com/ubuntu icinga-${DIST} main" >> \
 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/${DIST}-icinga.list
```